# Find the rank of the string (with duplicates) using modular multiplicative inverse

Tags: java, algorithm, rank

Here is code that works fine for string with length equal or less then 12 in case of int and 20 in case of long. In this code I use formula (N-1)! / (p1! * p2! * p3! ... ) for calculation of the rank, where p1, p2, p3 are the number of occurrences of repeated characters. But in case of large inputs result of factorial calculation does not fit in an integer (or long). So, I don't understand what part of code do i need to fix and how? Do I need to fix factorial method or do i need change formula for calculation of rank? As far as i know according to modular multiplicative inverse i can use formula  (A*power(B,Mod-2))%Mod, where A is iterativeFactorial(sorts.size()),B is countRepetitions(sorts) and Mod is 1000003. But if i place this formula instead of (N-1)! / (p1! * p2! * p3! ... ) i've got incorrect result.
So, I will be very grateful for clarification of using modular multiplicative inverse for calculating rank and the way I can fix my code for large input.

Example: rank of "adfadfcvcvbgfgrewfdfdsfgfgfhfhcxxse" must be 874647, but now I've got 511521

```
public static int myFindRank(String A){
        int rank = 0;
        String sortedAndUnique = "";
        int temp;
        Set<Character> uniques = new TreeSet<Character>();
        List<Character> sorts = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i<=A.length()-1; i++){
            char x = A.charAt(i);
            uniques.add(x);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<=A.length()-1; i++){
            char x = A.charAt(i);
            sorts.add(x);
        }

        for (Character c : uniques) {
            sortedAndUnique = sortedAndUnique + c;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<A.length()-1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<A.length(); j++){

                if (A.charAt(i) == sortedAndUnique.charAt(j)) {
                    Character c = A.charAt(i);
                    sorts.remove(c);
                    i++;
                    temp = 0;

                    while (sortedAndUnique.charAt(temp) != A.charAt(i)) {
                        Character x = sortedAndUnique.charAt(temp);
                        temp++;
                        if (sorts.contains(x)) {
                            sorts.remove(x);
                            rank = rank + iterativeFactorial(sorts.size())/ countRepetitions(sorts);
                            sorts.add(x);
                        }
                    }

                    if (sortedAndUnique.charAt(temp) == A.charAt(i)) {
                        Character y = A.charAt(i);
                        sorts.remove(y);
                    }
                    break;
                } else {
                    Character c = sortedAndUnique.charAt(j);
                    if (sorts.contains(c))  {
                        sorts.remove(c);
                        rank = rank + iterativeFactorial(sorts.size())/ countRepetitions(sorts);
                        sorts.add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (rank+1)%1000003;
    }


public static int countRepetitions(List A){

        int repetitions = 1;

        List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
        Set<Character> unique = new TreeSet<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i<=A.size()-1; i++){
            Character x = (Character) A.get(i);
            chars.add(x);
            unique.add(x);

        }

        for (Character c : unique) {
            repetitions = repetitions * iterativeFactorial(Collections.frequency(chars, c));

        }
        return repetitions;

    }


public static int iterativeFactorial(int number) {

        if (number == 0)
            return 1;

        int i;
        for(i=number; number>1; i=i*number) {
            number--;

        }
        return i;
    }
```

Custom power method:

```
 public static int callPow(int num)

    {

        int ans = 1, base = num;

        int power = 1000003 - 2;

        while (power > 0) {

            if (power == 1) {

                return (ans * base) % 1000003;

            }

            if (power % 2 == 0) {

                base = (base * base) % 1000003;

                power /= 2;

            } else {

                ans = (ans * base) % 1000003;

                power--;

            }

        }

        return ans;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as i know according to modular multiplicative inverse i can use formula (A*power(B,Mod-2))%Mod,

While mathematically correct, this can overflow. You need to use the modulo at each step:

```
[(A % Mod) * (power(B, Mod - 2) % Mod)] % Mod
```

So in your code:

```
    for(i=number; number>1; i=i*number) {
```

Change to:

```
    for(i=number; number>1; i=(i*number) % Mod) {
```

---

```
repetitions = repetitions * iterativeFactorial(Collections.frequency(chars, c));
```

Change to:

```
repetitions = (repetitions * iterativeFactorial(Collections.frequency(chars, c))) % Mod;
```

---

**Note:** you should use data types such that `Mod*Mod` fits in them!

And I'm not sure what you're doing in your first method. You should not have any divisions where the modulo operation is involved. Use the power formula you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've used  for(i=number; number>1; i=(i*number) % Mod) in previous version of this code, but I didn't use repetitions = (repetitions * iterativeFactorial(Collections.frequency(chars, c))) % Mod; and for that reason I've got incorrect result.

But if I use formula (A*power(B,Mod-2))%Mod where

A = iterativeFactorial(sorts.size());
B = countRepetitions(sorts);
Mod = 1000003;

I've still got incorrect result: "adfadfcvcvbgfgrewfdfdsfgfgfhfhcxxse" = 816783 instead of 874647 and for "bbbaaa" = -313504 instead of 20.

Comment: In code it looks like: rank = rank + (A*callPow(B))% 1000003;

Also I use custom power method (I've added this method to my post) for that calculation.

Comment: @ivan_ochc like I said, you need to use data types that can store `1000003*1000003` in them. In Java, I believe this would be `long`. Change your ints to longs.

Comment: BigInteger fits 1000003*1000003 in Java. Thanks a lot! I've fixed all bugs and now code works correctly for large inputs.